# Download anything

Tags: download

Is there any app you're aware of (CLI, GUI, or even a library in some language) that will simply download almost any file on any protocol I throw at it?

Seems like something that should exist, right?

Of course such an app would have to gracefully handle a very large number of error conditions and protocols.

For simply "acquiring" some content, all the millions of permutations of technical details just_don't_matter.

Comment: The usual suspects are `wget`, `curl` and [aria2](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/) (which also supports Bittorrent).

Comment: No. HTTP is completely different from UUCP is completely different from NFS… A web browser with lots of plugins installed is your best bet.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `wget` which will download anything you can specify a URI for. Other programs to look at include `curl` and there any any number of short recipies in Perl and Python to download with ease.

Comment: Wget speaks HTTP and FTP, and that's it. Curl speaks a bit more, but that still leaves out rsync, bittorrent, samba, NFS, UUCP, SMTP, POP3, IMAP, NNTP, etc.